# Evaluation of $\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x) \cdot dx$ for given definition of $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

If $f(x)=\sin x$, $\forall x \in \big[0, \pi/2 \big]$ $f(x)+f(\pi-x)=2$, $\forall x \in \big(\pi/2, \pi \big]$ and $f(x)=f(2\pi-x)$ $\forall x \in \big(\pi, 2\pi \big]$, then find area enclosed by $y=f(x)$ and $x-axis$?

Now we have

$$A=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin x \cdot dx+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} f(x) \cdot dx+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} f(2\pi-x) dx$$

For third integral I put $x=t+\pi$ to get

$$=1+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} f(x) \cdot dx+\int_{0}^{\pi} f(\pi-x)dx$$

$$=1+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} f(x) \cdot dx+\int_{0}^{\pi/2} f(\pi-x)dx+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} f(\pi-x)dx$$

On solving I got $A=2+\pi$ but given answer is $2 \pi$. Could someone point out my mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider three regions:

> $0 < x < \pi/2$

$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}{\rm d}x~f(x) = \int_0^{\pi/2}{\rm d}x~\sin(x) = 1 \tag{1}
$$

> $\pi/2 < x < \pi$

In this region note that

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{\pi/2}^\pi{\rm d}x~f(x) &=& \int_{\pi/2}^\pi{\rm d}x~(2 - f(\pi -x)) = 2\frac{\pi}{2} -\int_{\pi/2}^\pi{\rm d}x~f(\pi - x) \\
&\stackrel{t = \pi -x}{=}& \pi + \int_{\pi/2}^0{\rm d}t~f(t) \\
&\stackrel{(1)}{=}& \pi - 1 \tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}

Therefore

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}{\rm d}x~f(x) \stackrel{(1),(2)}{=} 1 + \pi - 1 = \pi \tag{3}
$$

> $\pi < x < 2\pi$

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}{\rm d}x~f(x) &=& \int_{\pi}^{2\pi}{\rm d}x~f(2\pi - x) \\
&\stackrel{t = 2\pi - x}{=}& -\int_{\pi}^{0}{\rm d}t~f(t) \\
&\stackrel{(3)}{=}& \pi \tag{4}
\end{eqnarray}

We then conclude

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\rm d}x~f(x) = \int_{0}^{\pi}{\rm d}x~f(x) + \int_{\pi}^{2\pi}{\rm d}x~f(x) = \pi + \pi = 2\pi
$$

You can actually arrive to this result faster by looking at the areas under the red curve

[image]